# Can I use PC3 ram in PC3L Slot?

Tags: webserver

I am using `M393B1K70DH0-YH9 SAMSUNG 8GB 2RX4 PC3L-10600R 1.35V MEMORY MODULE` (1X8GB) RAM in my DELL 730 server pc. I want upgrade my RAM. Available ram in market is

`M393B1K70DH0-YH9 SAMSUNG 8GB DDR3 1333MHZ PC3-10600 240-PIN CL9 ECC REGISTERED DIMM MEMORY` (FOR SERVER ONLY)

Can I use this with my old RAM together?

Comment: Your current memory is 1.5/1.35v but you have to determine what the motherboard supports.  So what does your motherboard support? I can’t determine if your current memory is ECC or not, that’s more important, than even the compatibility with the voltage levels. The specification page for DELL 730 should clarify if it supports ECC and what memory voltage it requires

Comment: I assume the part number being the same is in error, if so please correct, otherwise confirm it’s the same part number and the question can be closed

Answer (score 1):

According to the
[PowerEdge R730 manual](https://dl.dell.com/topicspdf/poweredge-r730_owners-manual2_en-us.pdf)
your RAM is 1.2V, so not even 1.35V, while PC3 needs 1.5V.
The difference in voltage is pretty large.

As a second opinion, the memory vendor
[Crucial](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/dell/poweredge-r730)
does not propose anything else but 1.2V RAM sticks for the PowerEdge R730.

I can't say if using that memory will work or not. I can say that
putting PC3 in a PC3L slot means basically undervolting the RAM rather
heavily. Even if it won't break anything, it could definitely cause
instabilities and errors.

If you plan on trying it, it would probably be a good idea to run
[MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/)
for some hours to see if the RAM is still stable or not.